# can we request a particular div from a website if it has multiple divs with the same name (python - requests and bs4)

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I was learning how to web **scrape** a website. I can remove all the data and the divs, but now the problem is how can I remove a particular div but there are multiple divs with the same name
**I have tried this -print(soup.find('div', class_= 'tv-widget-watch-list__last-wrap'))**
but it is giving me all the divs without any information, just the class of the div

Comment: It is quite possible that the HTML will contain more than one <div> with identical class attributes. There would have to be something unique about the <div> for you to be able to decide if it needs to be deleted.

Comment: i don't  want to delete the div i want to get the data from the website

Comment: I quote from your original question "...how can I remove a particular div..."

Comment: Please provide a short example descriping current result and expected result